# \usepackage[nomessages]{fp} and \FPeval{\X}{clip(0)}

Tags: letters, number

I do `\FPeval{\X}{clip(10)}` and `\X` save the number 10, so I need one function to change `\X`   (10)   to ten (letter) like

`\newfunction{\X}` out put ten

1. change one
2. change two
3. change three
4. change four

If it is possible in spanish with `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` it will be cool.

Comment: Welcome! I would be surprised if that did not exist somewhere already, but you can do `\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\ENum}[1]{\ifcase#1 
zero\or one\or two\or three\or four\or five\or six\or seven\or eight\or nine\or ten\fi}
\begin{document}
\ENum{5}
\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fmtcount`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\usepackage{fmtcount}

\begin{document}

\FPeval{\X}{clip(10)} % why?

\numberstringnum{\X}

\numberstringnum{1234}

\selectlanguage{italian}

\numberstringnum{\X}

\numberstringnum{1234}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks very much

Comment: thanks very much, only work with integer numbers, no decimal, anyway thanks